# Why doesn't java compiler complain about ambiguity here?

Tags: java, maven

Here `qux` module has 2 dependencies on `bar` and `baz` modules both of which contain identially named `lorem` packages and identically names `Ipsum` classes. How come there is no error?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lic5n.png

[image]

Comment: because there is no ambiguity, the first one loaded will win at runtime, always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allowed to do this in Java.  The classpath is ordered, and generally, the first class it finds will be the one it uses.  The other ones are not used.